# \endscname error using package matlab-prettifier

Tags: matlab-prettifier

I'm trying to prepare a beamer document using the matlab-prettifier package but I come across errors whenever I include a frame where I use code. I always get the following log:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \relax 
l.2 ...atlab-editor, basicstyle=\mlttfamily,\tiny]

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\KV@split ...csname \KV@prefix \@tempa \endcsname 
                                              \ifx \@tempc \relax \KV@er...
l.2 ...atlab-editor, basicstyle=\mlttfamily,\tiny]

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.


! Package keyval Error: \relax \fontsize {6}{7}\selectfont  undefined.
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} [fragile]
\frametitle{STEP 2: Parameters extraction - application}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor, basicstyle=\mlttfamily,\tiny]
par_out.T(1:r, 1:r*p)    = Eaa_FB(1:r, :)/Eaa_BB;
par_out.Q(1:r, 1:r)      = (Eaa(1:r, 1:r) - par_out.T(1:r, 
1:r*p)*Eaa_FB(1:r, :)')/m;
par_out.P0(1:r*p, 1:r*p) = Ps(1:r*p, 1:r*p, 1);

%% Idiosyncratic components
% Get kalman output and initialise estimation
for i=1:n   
ind_start  = r*p+1+(i-1)*q; 
ind_vec    = ind_start:ind_start+q-1;
as_i       = as(ind_vec, :);
Ps_i       = Ps(ind_vec, ind_vec, :);
PPs_lag1_i = PPs_lag1(ind_vec, ind_vec, :);
as_i_t     = as_i(:, 2:end);
as_i_t_1   = as_i(:, 1:end-1);
end 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a simple comma that is not allowed there. Just use `\mlttfamily\tiny`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} [fragile]
\frametitle{STEP 2: Parameters extraction - application}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor, basicstyle=\mlttfamily\tiny]
par_out.T(1:r, 1:r*p)    = Eaa_FB(1:r, :)/Eaa_BB;
par_out.Q(1:r, 1:r)      = (Eaa(1:r, 1:r) - par_out.T(1:r, 
1:r*p)*Eaa_FB(1:r, :)')/m;
par_out.P0(1:r*p, 1:r*p) = Ps(1:r*p, 1:r*p, 1);

%% Idiosyncratic components
% Get kalman output and initialise estimation
for i=1:n   
ind_start  = r*p+1+(i-1)*q; 
ind_vec    = ind_start:ind_start+q-1;
as_i       = as(ind_vec, :);
Ps_i       = Ps(ind_vec, ind_vec, :);
PPs_lag1_i = PPs_lag1(ind_vec, ind_vec, :);
as_i_t     = as_i(:, 2:end);
as_i_t_1   = as_i(:, 1:end-1);
end 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!! The time I spent trying to fix this seems so stupid now :D

Comment: @ezgikurt If that solved your problem consider accepting the answer (green button on the left).